# Skyrim PS4 - Solitude and Blue Palace not appearing on map

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Decided to start playing Skyrim again. I completed the civil war story line a while back, I sided with the Stormcloaks and after the Battle of Solitude the icon for Solitude and the Blue Palace are no longer displayed on the map. I only discovered this was an issue when going through the Dark brotherhood story line as I can no longer advance in 'The Silence Has Been Broken' quest since Astrid claims that I am responsible for the siege of solitude, and she will only speak to me once I have finished the battle. I am also the Thane of Eastmarch and tried speaking to Ulfric post battle and nothing has worked yet.